# getStaticPaths not recognizing new routes from database in NextJS

Tags: next.js, vercel, next-router

I have a NextJS website where I'm using `getStaticPaths` to generate the routes for a page. It fetches the paths from a database. The problem is that when I add a new route to the database, it doesn't recognize the new route and gives a 404 error.

Here's my code for `getStaticPaths`:

```js
export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
  const posts: Post[] = await getPosts()
  return {
    paths: posts.map((post: Post) => mountPath(post)),
    fallback: false,
  }
}
```

Even when I set `fallback` to `true`, it goes to the page fallback, but the `revalidate` option in `getStaticProps` doesn't seem to work and isn't able to get the content from database, even when the revalidate is expired.

Here's my code for `getStaticProps`:

```js
export const getStaticProps = async (context: any) => {
  const { slug } = context.params
  const post: any = await getPostBySlug(slug)

  let props = {
    post: post,
  }

  props = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(props))
  return {
    props,
    revalidate: 60 * 60 * 1,
  }
}
```

The site is deployed on Vercel, and based on the logs, it recognizes the URLs generated by `getStaticPaths` as ISR (Incremental Static Regeneration) Functions. It also recognizes the URL pattern `[year]/[month]/[slug]`, which matches the routes generated by `getStaticPaths`.

[image: Log from Vercel]

To work around this, I currently have to manually rebuild the site whenever a content is edited. Although the site is small now, I believe NextJS should be able to handle this automatically. I've been doing this workaround for two weeks now, always trying to change something to fix that.

So, I have two related problems:

Firstly, even with a revalidate interval of 1 hour, changes to the content are not reflected unless I manually rebuild.

Secondly, the `getStaticPaths` function doesn't recognize new routes that are inserted into the database.

Any help or suggestions on how to resolve these issues would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!